# Misunderstanding or typo in documentation for FFTW using OpenMP

Tags: openmp, fftw

This quote is from the [FFTW Manual](http://www.fftw.org/doc/Usage-of-Multi_002dthreaded-FFTW.html#Usage-of-Multi_002dthreaded-FFTW):

> [...] Third, before creating a plan that you want to parallelize, you should
>   call:
>
> `void fftw_plan_with_nthreads(int nthreads);`
>
> The nthreads argument indicates the number of threads you want FFTW to use (or actually, the
>   maximum number). [...]
>
> With OpenMP, to configure FFTW to use all of the currently running
>   OpenMP threads (set by omp_set_num_threads(nthreads) or by the
>   `OMP_NUM_THREADS` environment variable), you can do:
>   `fftw_plan_with_nthreads(omp_get_num_threads()`).

I think the last command is wrong. It should be `fftw_plan_with_nthreads(omp_get_max_threads())`. `omp_get_num_threads()` will return the current number of threads. But that is probably `1` because one is creating the fftw_plan on one thread. `omp_get_num_threads()` will not return the value of `OMP_NUM_THREADS` and is not the inverse of `omp_set_num_threads(nthreads)`.

Am I right or do I misunderstand either the FFTW or OpenMP API?

Comment: I think you misunderstand the OpenMP documentation, eg http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libgomp/omp_005fget_005fnum_005fthreads.html.  When called inside a parallel region the function returns the number of threads in the team.

Comment: But why would I create an fftw_plan in a parallel region?

Comment: That would only make sense if that function is to be called by a single thread inside the parallel region. Please, write an email to the FFTW team and tell them to correct the manual or to clarify it.

Comment: Ahaa, now I see it. The manual says: "... to use all of the CURRENTLY RUNNING OpenMP threads..." So the function call is correct but you should only make it in a single thread, e.g. with the `single` or `master` directive.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the feedback. I wrote them an e-mail.